# GCE Australia region VPC automatic subnetwork assignment

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to create a new server instance using the australia region (any zone) within GCE, but the automatic VPC network does not seem to have the australia zone listed?

This means there is not a subnetwork available for any of the new australian regions.

When I try on another project that uses the "legacy" type, it then automatically assigns an internal IP from my global subnetwork.

Is there a way to manually add a subnetwork to the automatic type, or do I need to switch the VPC to custom, then add the subnetwork?

I don't want to switch to custom if it will not allow me to do this, as I can see that you can't go back!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a new GCP Region is released, it is available for all GCP users by:

1. [Creating a new custom VPC](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpc/using-vpc#create-custom-network) and adding a subnet for the new region
2. [By converting the current default auto VPC to a custom VPC](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpc/using-vpc#switch-network-mode) and adding a subnet for the new region
3. Waiting a day or so, as soon after the release of the region, GCP projects are updated, so that the default VPC will have a subnet for the new region